# Merge and synonymize [fab] into [floating-action-button]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[fab](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fab) has 3 questions and a usage description.

[floating-action-button](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button) has 13 questions, and is much more descriptive ('fab' is not an acronym I was familiar with before seeing this tag, but maybe others' experiences differ).

I propose merging [fab](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fab) to make it a synonym for [floating-action-button](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button), and copying over its usage description as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag has been merged and synonymized.